# Texts in some cells arent displayed fully in Android google sheets app?

Tags: google-sheets, google

I have a Google Sheet with many cells that contain a lot of text.  Those cells have their formatting set to "wrap" and they display as expected in the Web Application (Chromium-based Whale Browser).  In other words, the row height automatically increases in order to allow the cell's contents to be fully displayed.

When displaying the same Sheet in the Android App, the cell height is no longer enough to fit the cell's content, and some of the content is hidden.

The screenshots below illustrate what I mean.  The example cell is selected in each.  This cell is representative of others in the same sheet.

The problem also occurs on my Galaxy Tab.  Is there something I can do to ensure the formatting remains the same in the Android app?

<sub>**Web App: Cell Contents Fully Displayed**   *(Whale Browser, Win10)*</sub>
[image]

<sub>**Android App: Cell Contents Partially Hidden**</sub>
[image]

Comment: I can't replicate your problem.  Please edit your question with a shared spreadsheet that exhibits the problem.  You can use the [Blank Sheet Maker](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSeprZS3Al0n7JiVQIEiCi_Ad9FRXbpgB7x1-Wq6iAfdmVbWiA/viewform) to create a shareable spreadsheet that doesn't expose your identity the forum.

Comment: Welcome to [webapps.se]. [tag:google] should not be used when using a more specific tag for a Google web app. Questions about Android App are off-topic here, you might try [android.se]. Use a supported web browser. While including a link to an external spreadsheet might be helpful, please remember that posts on this site should be self-contained. When adding sample data, set your language settings to English or your spreadsheet to use function names in English. Also include the relevant spreadsheet settings like the country setting.

Comment: In the event the data is only viewed in the Android app and never edited there, consider using **File > Share > Publish to web** instead of **File > Share > Share with others** to let others view the data.